# What are those icons in the top left of the hibernation screen?

Tags: rain-world

As the title says: what are those icons in the top left corner?

[image: Hibernation screen]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You killed some creatures during this life. The crossed bones and "~" are followed by icons representing the types of creatures you killed; in this case they were

> A [pole plant](https://rainworld.miraheze.org/wiki/Pole_Plant) and a [squidcada](https://rainworld.miraheze.org/wiki/Squidcada).

Comment: Thanks. So far the game is fun, but at times also a bit obscure with its unexplained symbols.